# delete LinkedList Repeated Items

Tags: java

i want to delete repeated items in linked list, iwould like to keep a unique items in the list, any idea how to do it ?
note:Hashset is forbided in this homework

All data structures used in this project must be implemented by the students.
The use of Java collections or any other library is strictly forbidden.

```
class Node<T> {
public T data;
public Node<T> next;

public Node (T val) {
    data = val;
    next = null;
}}
```

the following is LinkeList class

```
public class LinkedList<T> {
private Node<T> head;
private Node<T> current;

public LinkedList () {
    head = current = null;
}

public boolean empty () {
    return head == null;
}

public boolean last () {
    return current.next == null;
}

public boolean full () {
    return false;
}

public void findFirst () {
    current = head;
}
public void findNext () {
    current = current.next;
}

public T retrieve () {
    return current.data;
}

public void update (T val) {
    current.data = val;
}

public void insert (T val) {
    Node<T> tmp;
    if (empty()) {
        current = head = new Node<T> (val);
    }
    else {
        tmp = current.next;
        current.next = new Node<T> (val);
        current = current.next;
        current.next = tmp;
    }
}

public void remove () {
    if (current == head) {
        head = head.next;
    }
    else {
        Node<T> tmp = head;
        while (tmp.next != current)
            tmp = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = current.next;
    }
    if (current.next == null)
        current = head;
    else
        current = current.next;
}}
```

LinkedList Elements

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Integer> list=new LinkedList<>();

    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(2);
    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(3);
    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(2);
    list.insert(4);
    list.insert(3);
    list.insert(5);
    list.insert(4);
    list.insert(7);
    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(6);
    list.insert(5);
    list.insert(6);
    list.insert(1);
    list.insert(2);}
```

I've been stuck with this please help

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a `contain()` method (Note that this code is inspired from the `LinkedList` code source, you can check it [`LinkedList.contains(Object o)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29))

```
public boolean contain(T o) {
    if (o == null) { // assuming that your list accept to add null object
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (x.data == null)
                return true;
        }
    } else {
        for (Node<T> x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            if (o.equals(x.data))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And edit your `insert()` method to check if the object already exist before adding it

```
public void insert (T val) {
    Node<T> tmp;
    if (empty()) {
        current = head = new Node<T> (val);
    }
    else if(!contain(val)) { // the object val will be added only if it not exist in the list
        tmp = current.next;
        current.next = new Node<T> (val);
        current = current.next;
        current.next = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to sort the linked list for which you can use 'mergesort Linked List' which you can easily find on net and then delete repeated while traversing the list once. Complexity would be O(nlogn).
Link :http://algorithms.tutorialhorizon.com/merge-sort-in-a-linked-list/

OR

2) Check for every element from beginning and delete the repeating node while traversing the whole LL for each node.
 Complexity: O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

Use hashset and insert root into it if its not null.
Now start traversing and if next element is in hashset delete it otherwise insert it into hashset and keep traversing.

If hashset is forbidden then sort it and if next element is equal to current delete it otherwise keep traversing.

See [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/)

Comment: i know hashset but it is forbidden to be used

Comment: can you give me a hint how to sort it

Comment: In case you want sorting code in java, i can give you mine once i am free. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "one", "one", "two");
List<String> unique=list.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: i have to use only LinkedList